# Sexy Polling joomla how to show results not update the whole page

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

Me and my friend are administering one joomla site. And we have the Sexy Polling module, problem is that when you vote in that module, whole page refreshes. So is there anyway to put updatepanel from ajax or something like that so that when you vote it only show results not refresh the whole page?

Comment: Depends on if the reloading of the page is a part of the module. If it's just your code, then it's not that hard - you will just have to implement Ajax calling after the action which is performed, instead of redirecting. Otherwise if it's a part of the module you might have to overwrite their code or seek help from the makers of that module.

Comment: adding Ajax into a module that includes adding and retrieving data from the database is rather hard when using a module. Unless someone has a lot of time to spare, I doubt you will get an answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If Sexy Polls does not offer an Ajax poll module, it was the wrong choice.

Look at the [Joomla! Extension Directory, category Polls](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/polls). There you'll find a lot of poll components. Some of them have an Ajax poll module.

Answer (score 0):

Look at original Sexy Polling component - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/polls/23470

It uses ajax technology.